# In php must get data from jquery [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

With jquery create array. With ajax ($.post) send the array and additional data to php. In php see [object Object]. And can not get data from [object Object].

Tried the below code:

```
var data_to_send = []; // actually here is is input fields .serializeArray()

var cars = ["Sa,coma,ab", "Vol,coma,vo", "B,coma,MW"];

data_to_send.push( 
{name: 'draft', value: 'some_value'}, 
{name: 'cars_init', value: {name: 'cars', value: cars}} 
);

$.post( filename.php, data_to_send, function(data_process_invoices) {
$('#show_result').html(data_process_invoices).css('color', 'black');
});
```

In php with `echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre><br/>';` get like this

```
Array
(
    [draft] => some_value
    [cars_init] => [object Object]
)
```

Tried to get something from `[cars_init]`.

```
$array = get_object_vars( $_POST['cars_init'] );
```

Result is `[object Object]`.

Tried `$array = json_decode(($array), true);` and `foreach( $_POST['cars_init'] as $val ) { echo '<pre>', print_r( $val, true), '</pre><br/>'; }`. As result see nothing. And also get php errors `get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. As i understand for `php` `[cars_init]` is string... so question seems, how to convert it to array.

Instead of `[object Object]` just want to get array like this

```
 (
 [0] => Sa,coma,ab
 [1] => Vol,coma,vo
 [2] => B,coma,MW
 )
```

If i change jquery to `$.post( filename.php, {data_to_send}, function(data_process_invoices) {` i get some php array (with `$_POST`). But in such case get additional dimension and i need to use `foreach` to change (wasting of resources).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arrayOne = [{name:'a',value:1}, {name:'b',value:2}]
var arrayTwo = [{name:'foo',value:'blah'},{name:'arrayOne',value:arrayOne}];
```

Since you have a complex data structure, you should probably use JSON to encode your data:

```
data: {data: JSON.stringify(arrayTwo)},
```

and on the server you simply decode it with

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

`$data` will have the exact same structure as `arrayTwo`.

But in case you want to actually have parameters with names `foo` and `arrayOne`, then you only need to serialize the the value of `arrayOne`:

```
data:  [
  {name:'foo',value:'blah'},
  {name:'arrayOne',value: JSON.stringify(arrayOne)}
],
```

and in PHP:

```
$arrayOne = json_decode($_POST['arrayOne'], true);
```

Comment: Thanks, all works. Just needed to use `JSON.stringify`. I spend (wasted) ~ 5 hours "experimenting". Need to remember for future